# Create an empty list of Object type in java

Tags: java

How to create an empty list of Object type in java?

I'm trying to create a list of the following object.

```
List<Categories> catList= new List<Categories>();
```

I've imported the module `java.util.List`, However I'm getting the error "cannot instantiate the type List"

Btw I've tried with this and I'm getting this error "the local variable has not been initialized"

```
   List<Categories> catList;
   catList.add(categoryItem);
```

Comment: it does, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

`List` is an [interface and cannot be directly created](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). Instead you create an object based on a class that implements the methods in that interface. There are many classes that implement `List`, but a common one is `ArrayList`, which is probably what you want:

```
List<Categories> catList = new ArrayList<Categories>();
```

Note that it is still considered good practice to use the interface on the left side of this statement.

Some more info:

- [Interfaces in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)
- [The List interface and its methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lists don't necessarily do what I think you want them to. Switch to ArrayList on both sides of the line. Or switch the right side to `new ArrayList<Categories>() ;`

Answer (score 0):

The List interface is instantiated with either an ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector, or Stack. You can not instantiate it as a List. It will need to be something like `List<Categories> catList= new ArrayList<Categories>();`